# Loop over a function and use its random output within a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I improve this code:

```
import random
def rand_mac():
    return "00:00:00:%02x:%02x:%02x" % (
        random.randint(0, 255),
        random.randint(0, 255),
        random.randint(0, 255)
        )
add_acl_mac = rand_mac()
add_acl = 'mac access-list extended name test deny src {}-{} dst any\r\n'.format(add_acl_mac, add_acl_mac)
acl_list = 1
while (acl_list <=1024):
    network.sendline(add_acl)
    acl_list += 1
```

Current behavior: the loop writes the same MAC 1023 times.

Proposed behavior: the loop will write at each iteration a different MAC, for 1023 times.

I've been reading about generators and yield but I fail to understand how to properly use them in my current situation, if indeed they are to be used.

Thanks!

Comment: Call your function in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the lines

```
add_acl_mac = rand_mac()
add_acl = 'mac access-list extended name test deny src {}-{} dst any\r\n'.format(add_acl_mac, add_acl_mac)
```

inside the `for` loop.

Currently you are generating `add_acl` with the output from `rand_mac()` only once.

Answer (score 1):

```
for _ in range(1024):
    add_acl_mac = rand_mac()
    add_acl = 'mac access-list extended name test deny src {}-{} dst any\r\n'.format(add_acl_mac, add_acl_mac)
    network.sendline(add_acl)
```

put the mac generation code inside loop as well.